# Differences and relations between Console's static IO methods and Console.In/Out/Error's IO methods?

Tags: c#

In c# and .Net framework, what are the differences between

- the static read and write methods of `System.Console` class,  and
- the read and write methods of `TextReader`'s object `Console.In`, `TextWriter`'s objects `Console.Out`, `Console.Error`?

Do `System.Console.Write` and `System.Console.WriteLine` methods work the same as `System.Console.Out.Write` and `System.Console.Out.WriteLine`, or as `System.Console.Error.Write` and `System.Console.Error.WriteLine`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see for yourself by browsing the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,748bde83a8b838d8):

```
public static int ReadLine()
{
    return In.ReadLine();
}

public static void WriteLine()
{
    Out.WriteLine();
}
```

The static methods just call the equivalent methods on the `In` and `Out` `TextWriter` properties.